Statistical test for bias to even sizes
I'm studying an experiment which should follow a type of birth-death process, which tells me the number of cells at a certain time from the same lineage.
So, I have a discrete empirical distribution that approximately follows a geometric distribution over time. Based on a model which explains some other observation, we believe their may be a bias to even counts over odd, and we do see this. What is an appropriate hypotheses test for a bias to even counts is statistically significant from the samples at different time-points?
I thought of a one-sample proportion test where I compare to the expected fraction of even counts from the geometric distribution based on the mean at given time-points. But I'm not a statistician so I don't know if this is valid, or if theres a better approach.

Please explain what a "size" might refer to in this context.

@mathisfun The exponential is continuous. Do you mean the geometric?

Re the edited (and much clearer!) version: simplify.  Because you are concerned about count parity, what you have are a pair of counts at each "certain time:" counts of even results and counts of odd results.  That translates directly into standard solutions, including logistic regression (for more than two times) and t-tests (for two times).

Note that it is never valid to pick a test based on what you see in the data, as assumptions for any (standard) test do no condition on the data. So whatever is recommended here will only be valid when applied to new data.
